# Flexboxes in electron acting weird

Tags: html, css, flexbox, electron

I have 2 divs in my electron app. One on the left, with a fixed width, acting as a navigation menu. The other one is supposed to display content depending on which itme in the nav is clicked. For this right div I try to use `flex: 1;` in css to make it take up the remaining space in my wrapper div. In my jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/bhL8t7ny/) this worked perfectly fine. But of course in electron it didn't. I can't seem to find a valid fix though.

My html looks like this:

```
<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="sidebar">
      <div class="imgdiv">
        <img src="assets/icons/1x/logo_orange.png">
      </div>
      <div class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a id="dashboard" href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
          <li><a id="tasks" href="#">Tasks</a></li>
          <li><a id="profiles" href="#">Profiles</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content"></div>
  </div>

  <script src="../renderer.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/navigation.js"></script>
</body>
```

And css is as follows:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebar {
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #080808;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

.content {
    flex: 1;
    background: #141414;
}
```

I can't spot my mistake, this is exactly in line with what I used to test this out in the jsfiddle. Anyone know what's going wrong here?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized my idiotic mistake. I changed the content div's class to an id. So in css I would need to type `#content` instead of `.content` to be able to access that element.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using `flex-direction: column` in your code. You'll notice if you add `flex-direction: column` to your js-fiddle, it will also no longer work the way you want. Remove `flex-direction: column` since you want things placed in a row, not a column, and then you should be good to go! You could declare `flex-direction: row` if you really wanted, but since `row` is already the default flex direction, there is no need.

Comment: I don't think that's is. If I `add flex-direction: column;` to the jsfiddle it still works. Keep in mind the `flex-direction: column` applies to the children of that `.sidebar` div.